# Javascript comparisons not working with prompts, while loop, and !==

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

What I'm trying to do is prompt the user repeatedly until one of the accepted answers is received. Pretty easy stuff. The while loop, however, is making this really weird and annoying. Here's what I got:

```
var plrchoice=prompt("Would you like to choose Bulbasaur, Charmander, or Squirtle? (Use only lowercase characters)");
while(plrchoice!=="bulbasaur"||plrchoice!=="charmander"||plrchoice!=="squirtle"){
        plrchoice=prompt("Would you like to choose Bulbasaur, Charmander, or Squirtle?");
    }
```

This should work in theory, but the result is an infinite do/while, regardless of what the user inputs. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't be scared of white space :) it makes code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Those `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that worked! But that leads to another question... If && means "and", doesn't that mean that plrchoice must equal all of those strings? This obviously isn't the case, but why not?

Comment: @user2345707 nope, you're checking that they're !== which is not equal. || is correct if you're checking equality.

Answer (score 1):

If your rewrite the code like this, it may be clearer what happens:

```
var plrchoice = "";
while (!/^(bulbasaur|charmander|squirtle)$/i.test(plrchoice)) {
   plrchoice = 
     prompt("Would you like to choose Bulbasaur, Charmander, or Squirtle?");
}
```